# Infopath to Excel through code

Tags: sharepoint, moss, infopath, infopath-2007

I would like to convert data from infopath form to excel spreadsheet through code. 
I know you can export the data using the feature in infopath, but I am interested in doing this through code (like a part of a workflow).

Can anybody suggest a way for doing this or a possible starting point?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the xml data from the form to excel format.
Check this-[XMl to Excel](https://bytescout.com/support/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=83&nav=0,1,17)

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you're looking for something more advanced, check out http://openxmldeveloper.org/